# Call Trigger based off Case Field

Tags: apex, trigger, email

I only want this code to be called when a case field has a particular value or values. e.g. (A or B) or (A and B)

Finding it tricky to get this working in my trigger. Has anyone done this before?

```
EmailMessageTriggerHandler.addEmailAsCaseComment(Trigger.new);
EmailMessageTriggerHandler.sendCasesBackToQueues(Trigger.new);
```

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: Sorry didn't paste :(

Comment: You can click **edit** under your question and paste the code in.

Comment: Please post more code...... This isn't enough.....

Comment: public with sharing class EmailMessageTriggerHandler
{
  public static void addEmailAsCaseComment(List <EmailMessage> emailMessages)
  {
    List<CaseComment> lstCaseComment = new List<CaseComment>(); // empty list of case comments that we will populate and insert
    for(EmailMessage msg : emailMessages)
    {
      Integer lengthWithoutText = ('From: ' +  (msg.FromName != null ? msg.fromname : '') + '(' + msg.FromAddress + ')'  + '\n' +

Comment: 'Sent Date: ' + msg.CreatedDate).length();
      Integer lengthForText = 3500 - lengthWithoutText;
        
      system.debug('AAAAAA lengthForText:' + lengthForText);
      //Prepare Email Body
      String emailBody = '';
      if (msg.htmlBody <> '' && msg.htmlBody <> null){
        emailBody = convertHtmlBodyToText(msg.HtmlBody);
      }
      else if(msg.TextBody <> '' && msg.TextBody <> null)
      {
        emailBody = msg.TextBody; 
      }
      //Create Case Comment

Comment: system.debug('aaaaaa' + emailBody.length() + '  :' + lengthForText );
      if(emailBody.length() <= lengthForText)
      {
        lstCaseComment.add(prepareCaseComment(msg, emailBody));        
      }
      else
      {
        //If Email Body is more than 4000 characters, create mutiple case comments
        String str;
        Integer lastCharAt;
        List<CaseComment> tempList = new List<CaseComment>();
        while(emailBody.length() > lengthForText)
        lastIndexOf(' ') + 1;

Comment: {
          system.debug('bbbbbb' + emailBody.length());
          //lastCharAt = emailBody.substring(0, lengthForText ).lastIndexOf(' ') + 1;
          lastCharAt = emailBody.substring(0, lengthForText ).lastIndexOf(' ') + 1;   
          str = emailBody.substring(0, lastCharAt);
          tempList.add(prepareCaseComment(msg, str));
          system.debug('cccccc lastCharAt: ' + lastCharAt);
          emailBody = emailBody.substring(lastCharAt, emailBody.length());
          system.debug('dddddd' + emailBody.length());
        }
        if(emailBody.length() <= lengthForText)
        {

Comment: Please click **edit** on your question and add the code. You will be able to format it properly in the question. Adding code in the comments is unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is ambiguous. Please post your trigger code and not the class code. If you are using after trigger, you can try something like this.

```
list<Case> passtoController = new list<Case>();
for(Integer i=0; i<Trigger.new.size(); i++)
{
  if(Trigger.new[i].yourfieldname == 'A' || Trigger.new[i].yourfieldname == 'B')
    passtoController.add(Trigger.new[i]);

}
If(passtoController.size() > 0){
EmailMessageTriggerHandler.addEmailAsCaseComment(passtoController);
EmailMessageTriggerHandler.sendCasesBackToQueues(passtoController);
}
```